# Can transitions of a particle in an infinite square well end at a state that is not the ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, atomic-physics

As we know, in an infinite square well, the energy is quantised and is given by $$E_n=\frac{n^2h^2}{8mL^2}$$
Now, suppose that there is an electron in the fourth excited state. Now, let us suppose that the electron starts going down to lower energy levels, thereby emitting photons in the process.
My question is-
Is it possible that it does not *reach* the ground state? Is it possible that it just stops after $N=4$ to $N=2$ transition?

Comment: What is the Hamiltonian for this system? It can't be the ordinary single-particle-in-an-infinite-square-well Hamiltonian can it?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri What makes you state that, AC? The energy equation BP uses is that of the infinite square 1D well, no? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#Energy_levels

Comment: @Gert I think the point AC is getting at is what Vadim explains in their answer: *only* having a particle in an infinite well will not allow for energy transitions, as energy states are stationary for the Hamiltonian of the infinite well.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Well, live and learn. I didn't know that. Ta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the process that causes the transitions. If you have only the quantum well and nothing else, the electron will forever stay in the state where one puts it. The transitions occur when the electron is also coupled, e.g., to a photon or phonon field, so it can go to lower stats by emitting photons/phonons with energy
$$\hbar\omega_{n\rightarrow n-1} = E_n - E_{n-1}.$$ 
One could now imagine a situation where emitting photon of energy $\hbar\omega_{2\rightarrow 1}$ is impossible, e.g., if we are dealing with an atom in a cavity that does not have $\omega_{2\rightarrow 1}$ among its resonance frequencies. Then the electron will be stuck for a long time in state $n=2$, and we would call it a *metastable state*.

The problem is that the rectangular well is a potential that does not represent much in real life - it is mainly used for illustrative purposes in the introductory QM. Thus, your question is too generic to come up with an appropriate example.